# Why forbid previous employers as references?

Tags: recommendation-letter, job-search, faculty-application

Very rarely I have seen in faculty job application forms:

> Please list below names, addresses, and telephone numbers of references. Do not list the names of relatives or **previous employers.**

Why would a search committee *not* want the previous employer as a reference?

Comment: A wild guess could be that if it refers to industrial employers, these may only confirm that one worked there from date A to B and nothing more, resulting basically useless for the selection.

Comment: Another guess: If you have contact to a specific person, it is easy to get the information from them. When you have contact to a (large) company, then it will likely be hard to get through to someone who is able to give the required info.

Comment: But employer is not necessarily industrial. Many people might work in a (partnership) consultancy, for a government agency/laboratory, a media-related job demanding certain professional expertise, e.g. trade journalism or PR. Maybe we should give more attention to the word **previous**. By this they may mean all employers prior to one's **current** employer. This makes sense as the passage of time the memory of the applicant's strengths and weaknesses may fade in their ex-boss' mind. And there's no guarantee that his/her boss may still be there - or that the organization may still exist.

Comment: @Trunk passage of time and fading of memory is not the problem one would want to prevent, otherwise they would have asked for references with whom you've worked in the past X years.

Comment: OP, can you provide an actual example for this? I'm puzzled myself as I have never seen and cannot imagine this. My wild guess is that they want to motivate people to find references from academics, instead of the owner of the Starbucks where you've worked during your PhD, who is super friendly and happy to say the candidate is the nicest person alive but ultimately knows nothing about his research skills. In other words, it could be a nicer way to say "don't give us a reference we'll throw in the garbage bin, as we cannot ask you to replace it"

Comment: Well, if this stipulation is designed to provide more authenticity to the reference then maybe they want to get a better idea of **the person** - as opposed to the professional - that they are hiring. Assuming it's an academic job, they might seek a reference from a candidate's old college tutor or postgraduate supervisor. Providing a phone number for one of these would allow the hiring academic to call that person and informally discuss the character and personality of the candidate. Interviews can be formal set-pieces and references can be deadpan. Employers need to know applicants better.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely to be a case of 'not really saying what they meant to say'.

We cannot get inside the head of whoever designed the application form, and perhaps there is context that is missing here. However, taken literally the guidance would seem to prevent someone from (say) using their previous postdoc supervisor as a referee. This is so far from the usual practice in academia that I suspect it is a mistake. Instead, I would guess that the intention was to require referees who are:

1. named individuals who know you personally ("Brenda Smith, my former line manager"), not generic corporate identities ("The HR Manager, Acme, Inc."), and/or
2. people who can comment specifically on the candidate's academic credentials (so not "Bob Jones, Front-of-house manager, North Podunk Burger Shack").

I think it is easy to see how either or both of these requirements could end up getting expressed as "not your previous employer", especially if a form has undergone several rounds of editing.

I suggest anyone filling in this application form should contact the relevant department and seek clarification of exactly what they want.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Employers are liable for what is said in their references, thus information should not come from the employer.

References are usually the opinion of one person who has seen that person for a certain amount of time. This person may have had several reasons to provide an unfavorable opinion about the individual, whether it be personality clashes or just personal dissatisfaction with them as a worker.
This can lead to many other complications such as people being fired unfairly due to this misinformation spread by someone else. Employers are liable for what is said in their references so information should not come from the employer. Theoretically it should also be possible to find individuals willing to say something positive about coworker's service so there's no need for negative comments either way

Comment: Do you have any evidence that employers have different liability from individuals?

Comment: It depends on the country. Some countries have become litigious to an alarming degree.  Here is an example of a uni with concerns.  https://www.uah.edu/images/administrative/legal/pdf_files/legal_implications_of_lltrs_of_rec.pdf

Comment: Universities typically have far more resources than their individual employees.  Thus it can effective to sue the university for something that an employee said or did.

Answer (score 0):

##### An Employer as a Reference Would Be Unhelpfully Duplicative

By a properly formatted CV, the search committee already has access to that employer, in case the committee would want the employer's perspective. Thus, including an employer as a reference would be unhelpfully duplicative: adding nothing new, only restating the employer as a source to validate the applicant.

Answer (score -2):

Previous employers can be seen as being unable to give accurate references as time goes by, particularly if they have lots of employees or other work colleagues in the time since.  By requesting current employer references, they could be seen as receiving fresher, up-to-date, more accurate detailed information, including faults not shaded by the mists of time, and part of that would include employee/employer relations when the employee is seeking to leave.  For instance, my current workplace has 250 people or so working in this office.  I've had over 20 different managers in around 6 years.  There are several different linked offices that people get transferred to.  And people may be transferred out of that as well.  A manager may have had 400 or more people that they were directly supervising during that time, and that's if they hadn't changed positions during that time.  Such a manager isn't going to remember the details of those they were supervising 4-5-6 years previously.  A manager on the next tier up would have over a thousand employee contacts in the period.

The second factor, and not as nice, is that it puts pressure on the current employee/employer relationship to push an employee into moving towards leaving, and accepting the new position.  By pushing the potential employees towards a clearer intent to leave the current position, it sets a stronger mindset on the person to depart & not window-shop for positions; and also puts a wedge on the current relationship.

Finally, it reduces the options on a potential employee to pick a more favourable employer reference.  If I have 4 or 5 former employers, I'd choose the one I believe would give me the best reference.